# Entity Framework database-first approach Pascal case

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, camelcasing

I am using EF Core 3.0 with a database-first approach to `Scaffold-DbContext` from a SQL Server database:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext 
       scaffold "Server=***;Database=***;User Id=***;Password=****;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
       -o Models -c "MyContext" --project=Data
```

When the models are generated, it uses a specified naming for the variable for example:

if the column in the database called for example

- `ISBuy` becomes `Isbuy`
- `CategoryID` => `CategoryId`

and this really misses up my system ...

Is there is a way to prevent that converting and generate variable name with the same as database or is there is a super magical way to prevent just these and use camel case as EF Core does?

And I am not talking about the object that returned from the API because I found a lot of solutions for that case but never this one.

Thanks

Comment: Try the usedatabasenames parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `--use-database-names` in your .NET Core CLI,

```
dotnet ef dbcontext 
   scaffold "Server=***;Database=***;User Id=***;Password=****;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
   -o Models -c "MyContext" --project=Data --use-database-names
```

refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold

> --use-database-names
>   Use table and column names exactly as they appear in the database. If this option is omitted, database names are changed to more closely conform to C# name style conventions.

Answer (score 6):

In PowerShell, you can use the `UseDatabaseNames` option (with a single dash) as part of [a `Scaffold-DbContext` call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext) to keep the casing used in the database schema.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.\SERVERNAME;Database=DBNAME;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir ENTITIESDIR -Context "NameContext" -UseDatabaseNames
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered bad practice. Please add some details about how these solutions work to solve the problem.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @SuitBoyApps fixed.